# How to secure photos from downloading in a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, photos

I'm working on an asp.net MVC website that users can have photo albums in it...
I searched a lot and found out photos can be prevent from downloading(stealing) by few things like "Disabling right click", "Disabling the drag able property of images", "Using base 64 URLs" and "Watermark", but i didn't find 100% useful solution!!! I think Watermark is the best way, but it will make most photos ugly and they also can be erased with Photoshop! 
I'm not also worried about the fact that viewers can take screenshots, because photos will be shown in low resolution.

Is there other ways in addition to these solutions?

Comment: oh! did you forget screen grab??? :)

Comment: Yes I think. What's that?! :)

Comment: of all the things you mentioned, screen grab is another way to get the photos. If its on the web, anyone can steal. use a water mark which is almost invisible but shows when printed - a very light grayscale word over the image

Comment: so at last watermak is the winner... :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i didn't find 100% useful solution!!!

There is no such thing as a 100% html based solution.

You would have to do some type of Flash plugin and even then it's not 100% either, it would just make it harder.

Comment: oh,,, actually i'm a bit new in website, but every time I hear about flash, I think the loading speed of the website could be slow... is that right?

Comment: Like any application, it depends on how it is coded.